# Is there a way to disable the Mozilla Firefox file dialog like in Google Chrome?

Tags: firefox

I'm looking for a way to disable the file dialog popup in Firefox that appears when a user clicks on, for instance, an "Upload File" button on a website.

In Google Chrome, we achieve this by setting the "AllowFileSelectionDialogs" policy to 0 in the registry. Unfortunately, it seems that Mozilla Firefox does not offer a similar functionality. The operating system will be Windows 10.

Is there any way to achieve this in Firefox?

Comment: I don't think it exists.